# How do you programmatically change limit data expression in Spotfire JS Viz

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have the code below, which takes a string from a text area and adds it to the limit data expression of a Spotfire visualisation.  However when I try and run the code against a JS visualisation, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Data'

When running the same code on a Spotfire (native) visualization, it works fine with no issues. What do I need to change in the code to have the equivalent of `limit data by expression` box for a js viz?

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

for vis in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
    if vis.Title == 'Chart wizard area':
        ta= vis.As[HtmlTextArea]().HtmlContent

print ta


for vis1 in Application.Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
    if vis1.Title == 'chart viz': #if statement for testing
        print 'hello'
        visual = vis.As[Visualization]()
        visual.Data.WhereClauseExpression = ta
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible**

With IronPython you can only edit Spotfire objects. Js viz is a javascript object and thus it is unaccessible from IronPython.